# Choose highest sum of substrings without overlap using dictionary

Tags: string, python-3.x, algorithm, dictionary, dynamic-programming

We have some string for example

```
s = 'randomcaran'
```

and we have dictionary with substrings and numeric values:

```
d = {'ran': 2, 'ndo': 6, 'omca': 4, 'car': 3}
```

and we want to choose combination which returns the highest sum, without letters overlap, but substrings from dictionary d can be found in string s multiple times in random order. And of course string s can be different.

```
# result should be 9
# string s contains five substrings: 
#     ran   ndo   omca   car   ran            # ran is twice
#      2           4            2       == 8
#            6            3             == 9
```

or for this combination

```
d = {'ran': 4, 'ndo': 6, 'omca': 4, 'car': 3}
# result should be 12
# string s contains five substrings: 
#     ran   ndo   omca   car   ran            # ran is twice
#      4           4            4       == 12
#            6            3             == 9
```

Naive solution for first case might be:

```
result = s.count('ndo') * 6
result += s.count('car') * 3
```

I do not know how to solve this problem.

I̶'̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶r̶i̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶l̶s̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶w̶a̶y̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶r̶e̶g̶u̶l̶a̶r̶ ̶e̶x̶p̶r̶e̶s̶s̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶a̶b̶l̶y̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶w̶r̶o̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶p̶p̶r̶o̶a̶c̶h̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶s̶o̶m̶e̶ ̶s̶i̶m̶p̶l̶e̶r̶ ̶w̶a̶y̶,̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶ ̶s̶u̶g̶g̶e̶s̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶?̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶

```
i̶m̶p̶o̶r̶t̶ ̶r̶e̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶
r̶e̶s̶u̶l̶t̶ ̶=̶ ̶0̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶
f̶o̶r̶ ̶k̶,̶ ̶v̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶d̶.̶i̶t̶e̶m̶s̶(̶)̶:̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶
    r̶e̶s̶u̶l̶t̶ ̶+̶=̶ ̶v̶ ̶*̶ ̶r̶e̶.̶f̶i̶n̶d̶a̶l̶l̶(̶r̶'̶{̶0̶}̶?̶'̶.̶f̶o̶r̶m̶a̶t̶(̶k̶)̶,̶ ̶s̶)̶.̶c̶o̶u̶n̶t̶(̶k̶)̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶
    #̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶u̶l̶t̶ ̶+̶=̶ ̶v̶ ̶*̶ ̶s̶.̶c̶o̶u̶n̶t̶(̶k̶)̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶
p̶r̶i̶n̶t̶(̶r̶e̶s̶u̶l̶t̶)̶ ̶ ̶ ̶#̶ ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶s̶u̶m̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶a̶l̶l̶ ̶1̶7̶,̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶9̶
```

EDIT:
Maybe dynamic programming is the answer, but still I do not know how to properly start with this method in this case.

Comment: Off the top of my head, maybe compute score per letter (value / nr. of unique letters), sort by that, and select the elements in the obvious way. It may not give optimal result (would have to prove it---I haven't tried), but it's likely to work well (if it doesn't give optimal result it may be an approx. algo. in some sense).

Comment: @wokadakow how important is efficiency? I can probably come up with a recursive brute force method which would work, but there may be a smarter way... (btw. regex is not the way to go for this!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a variant of a known problem called "weighted interval scheduling". Basically there are two approaches:

1. Recursive brute force, with time complexity of O(n*2^n)
2. Dynamic programming, with time complexity of O(n*log(n))

You can read more about the problem and the solutions here: https://farazdagi.com/2013/weighted-interval-scheduling/
There are even python implementations for both solutions there!